# Centering a bootstrap footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to center a bootstrap footer on my page and I'm having problems. Right now, it's left aligned by default and I can't seem to find how to fix it after a many attempts over the last week - I'm stumped. Here's the code that I have so far...

Thanks for your help!

```
<footer>
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="footer">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="about.php">about</a></li>
          <li><a href="faq.php">faq</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact_feedback.php">contact us</a></li>
          <li><a href="contributions.php">donate</a></li>
          <li><a href="terms_of_use.php">terms of use</a></li>
          <li><a href="privacy_policy.php">privacy policy</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="navbar-footer">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#footer">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to alter your HTML, just add the following CSS to override Bootstrap's defaults:

```
.navbar-nav {
  text-align:center;
  float:none;
}
  .navbar-nav li {
      display:inline-block;
      float:none;
  }
```

## [Bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/qX1G0CRyVP)

Comment: Thank you kindly, that worked exactly as I wanted! and @everyone_else, Thank you as well for your help!

Answer (score 2):

could you put your footer within a row? Then you could put it in the center column.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2">
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
--- Your footer ---
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `text-align:center;` will take care of centring the text inside of their containers. As for the footer, you should put a div or any other container around the `<footer>` tag with the class "container" to center the footer. Alternatively just give the class `container` to your footer tag i.e.

```
<footer class="container">
    <!-- footer content etc -->
</footer>
```

It depends on your layout and style requirements!

Comment: `<footer>` isn't necessary, and the next div ***is*** a container... Plus everything is centered in the cell already.